# Find a person's origin from his/her face picture

Tags: images

I am looking for a library or program that when given a face picture of a human in English tries to find the person's origin(s) based on the features of his/her face: ideally, it would give the likelihood for each [origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_and_ethnicity_in_the_United_States_Census) (e.g. 0.8 Caucasian, 0.3 Asian, 0.1 Hispanic). If possible, free, open source, and works with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate or Ubuntu.

Comment: I have to wonder what you want to use this for ;)

Comment: @Undo Ethnicity statistics in a face database!

Comment: I hope not the airport database and immigrant pre-selection o_O Yeah, questions like this always raise "suspection"...

Comment: @Izzy Yes, I see what you mean: in the country where I grew up (viz. France) ethnicity statistics are banned by law.

Comment: This is a nice idea in the positive light :) But practically, I don't think algorithms can do any better where we humans ourselves cannot determine the "0.8 Caucasian, 0.3 Asian, 0.1 Hispanic" you were mentioning about. Because we need to set the rules for analysis and we don't know what they are.

Comment: @dbza This seems doable if you have a tool to extract metrics, and a sample database categorized by a human. Then you just need to train a neural network and use it.